# mysqli_fetch_assoc() is giving unexpected null values

Tags: php, mysql

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM users,content 
LEFT OUTER JOIN articles ON ( 
  content.content_id = articles.content_id 
  AND content.content_type = 'article' ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN projects ON ( 
  content.content_id = projects.content_id 
  AND content.content_type = 'project' )
LEFT OUTER JOIN videos ON ( 
  content.content_id = articles.content_id
  AND content.content_type = 'video' ) 
WHERE (content.content_id IN (128,414,399,616,259)) 
AND content.author_id = users.u_id 
order by FIELD(content.content_id,128,414,399,616,259)
```

when I run this on phpmyadmin I'm getting the results correctly but when I fetch the results by doing mysqli_fetch_assoc(), I am getting null values for content_id. Someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Edit:
This is my php code

```
$query = "SELECT * 
      FROM   users,content
        LEFT OUTER JOIN articles 
                    ON ( content.content_id = articles.content_id 
                         AND content.content_type = 'article' ) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN projects
                    ON ( content.content_id = projects.content_id 
                         AND content.content_type = 'project' ) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN videos 
                    ON ( content.content_id = articles.content_id 
                         AND content.content_type = 'video' ) 
      WHERE (content.content_id IN (".implode(",",$new_array).")) AND content.author_id = users.u_id order by FIELD(content.content_id,".implode(",",$new_array).")";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($result!=null && $result->num_rows>0){
    while( $contentrow = $mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){
      print_r($contentrow);
  }
}
```

$new_array is the content ids for which I'm querying the database. The printed $contentrow has content_id field as null while I'm getting the correct id values in phpmyadmin.

Comment: there's no code to support your question.

Comment: why did this question get an upvote?

Comment: If it runs correctly in phpmyadmin then there is a problem while printing values... can you show how are you printing values??

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't know. I don't see a reason to upvote this question. If you ask me a downvote would be more appropriate

Comment: Supporting code is added.

Comment: check if any errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: There is a field called 'content_id' in every table (and that is the foreign key) and I'm joining tables based on 'content_type' field in content table(for eg. if content_type corresponding to content_id 128 is article then I'm doing join articles). Probably this multiple columns with same name is creating the problem. Suggest something for this.